# HtmlAgilityPack algorithm question

Tags: html-agility-pack

I’m using HtmlAgilityPack to obtain some Html from a web site.

Here is the received Html:

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table class="innertable">...</table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><strong>Contact</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">John Doe</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">Jane Doe</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>Units</strong></td>
    <td>32</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>Year</strong></td>
    <td>1998</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

---

**The Context:**

I’m using the following code to get the first :

```
var table = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='table']").FirstOrDefault();
```

I’m using the following code to get the inner table :

```
var innerTable = table.SelectNodes("//table[@class=innertable]").FirstOrDefault();
```

So far so good!

I need to get some information from the first table and some from the inner table. 
Since I begin with the information from the first table I need to ***skip*** the first row (which holds the inner table) so I do the following:

```
var tableCells = table.SelectNodes("tr[position() > 1]/td");
```

Since I now have all the cells from the first table excluding the inner table, I start doing the following:

```
string contact1 = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(tableCells[1].InnerHtml);
string contact2 = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(tableCells[2].InnerHtml);

string units = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(tableCells[5].InnerHtml);
string years = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(tableCells[7].InnerHtml);
```

---

**The problem:**

I’m getting the values I want by **hardcoding** the index in tableCells[] not thinking the layout would move…unfortunately, it does move.

In some cases I do not have a “Jane Doe” row (as shown in the above Html), this means I may **or** may not have two contacts.

Because of this, I can’t hardcode the indexes since I might end up having the wrong data in the wrong variables.

So I need to change my approach...

Does anyone know how I could perfect my algorithm so that it can take into account the fact that I may have one **or** two contacts and perhaps not use **hardcoded** indexes?

Thanks in advance!

vlince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is never one unique solution to this kind of problem. Here is an XPATH that seems to do some kind of it though:

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(yourHtmlFile);

        doc.Save(Console.Out);

        foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[td/strong/text() = 'Contact']/following-sibling::tr/td/text()[. != '&nbsp;']"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.OuterHtml);
        }
```

will display this:

```
John Doe
Jane Doe
32
1998
```

Comment: Yes Simon, you are correct…there isn’t a unique way to do things :-)
Thanks for your post, it did make me think (rethink) my algorithm and I like what you’ve shown! Perhaps I need to read more on XPATH in order to come up with expressions like you did. Many thanks!